# How to ignore/handle Line Feed (0A) while using fread?

Tags: c

I'm currently trying to write a function that will translate each byte of input data into a define constant byte (assembly instruction).

```
void toASM(FILE *inputFile, FILE *outputFile) {
    char buffer[16 + sizeof(char)] = "";
    int bytes = 0;                       
    while ((bytes = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 16, inputFile))) {   // start reading block of data from stream
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
            if (i == bytes - 1) {
                if((buffer[i] != '\r') && (buffer[i] != '\n')) {           
                    fprintf(outputFile, "$%.2X\n", buffer[i]);
                } else {
                    printf("\n");
                }
            } else {
                fprintf(outputFile, "$%.2X,", buffer[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This function is working correctly the only issue I can't seem to solve is that at the end it will produce a '$0A' which I assume is a Line Feed or maybe a New Line.

My best guess is that my while loop is reading the last line of the input which in result returns '$0A'

Current Output for ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

```
$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$4A,$4B,$4C,$4D,$4E,$4F,$50
$51,$52,$53,$54,$55,$56,$57,$58,$59,$5A,
```

Output without the check for the Line Feed or New Line

```
$41, $42, $43, $44, $45, $46, $47, $48, $49, $4A, $4B, $4C, $4D, $4E, $4F, $50
$51, $52, $53, $54, $55, $56, $57, $58, $59, $5A, $0A
```

My desired Output

```
$41, $42, $43, $44, $45, $46, $47, $48, $49, $4A, $4B, $4C, $4D, $4E, $4F, $50
$51, $52, $53, $54, $55, $56, $57, $58, $59, $5A
```

The current issues is the extra ',' but the bigger issue is that if the input file contains multiple lines of data the ASM output will contain random new lines. This is due to my else statement doing the `printf("\n");`

So I'm wondering if there is a better alternative to do this?

Comment: What output do you expect if the input file consists of four lines each with the alphabet followed by a newline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code shows the technique I usually use.  It considers the comma-space as a prefix to items except the first; the first has an empty string as the prefix (or leading indentation if you want the data indented, or a label, or …).

```
#include <stdio.h>

static inline int iseol(unsigned char c) { return (c == '\n' || c == '\r'); }

static
void toASM(FILE *inputFile, FILE *outputFile)
{
    unsigned char buffer[16];
    int bytes;
    while ((bytes = fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer[0]), sizeof(buffer), inputFile)) > 0)
    {
        const char *pad = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
        {
            if (!iseol(buffer[i]))
            {
                fprintf(outputFile, "%s$%.2X", pad, buffer[i]);
                pad = ", ";
            }
            else if (pad[0] != '\0')
            {
                printf("\n");
                pad = "";
            }
        }
        if (pad[0] != '\0')
            putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    toASM(stdin, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

The `iseol()` function is probably overkill; using the original test was OK.  Formally, it is a [reserved identifier](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.31.2) — using `is_eol()` would be safe, as would `isEOL()`.

The program source was `asm67.c`, compiled to program `asm67`.
I test with an input file `input` with contents:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

The simplest test case yields:

```
$ asm67 < input
$41, $42, $43, $44, $45, $46, $47, $48, $49, $4A, $4B, $4C, $4D, $4E, $4F, $50
$51, $52, $53, $54, $55, $56, $57, $58, $59, $5A
$
```

That looks like what you requested.  The following shows the output from 4 lines of input each containing the alphabet plus a newline.  If that's not what you want, you should specify the desired output for such cases in the question.  The futzing required to get the desired output is probably not very complex.

```
$ cat input input input input | asm67
$41, $42, $43, $44, $45, $46, $47, $48, $49, $4A, $4B, $4C, $4D, $4E, $4F, $50
$51, $52, $53, $54, $55, $56, $57, $58, $59, $5A
$41, $42, $43, $44, $45
$46, $47, $48, $49, $4A, $4B, $4C, $4D, $4E, $4F, $50, $51, $52, $53, $54, $55
$56, $57, $58, $59, $5A
$41, $42, $43, $44, $45, $46, $47, $48, $49, $4A
$4B, $4C, $4D, $4E, $4F, $50, $51, $52, $53, $54, $55, $56, $57, $58, $59, $5A
$41, $42, $43, $44, $45, $46, $47, $48, $49, $4A, $4B, $4C, $4D, $4E, $4F
$50, $51, $52, $53, $54, $55, $56, $57, $58, $59, $5A
$
```

Note that with the 4 lines of input, one of the 16-byte blocks starts with a newline character; the code's logic with `if (pad[0] != '\0')` prevents that leaving a blank line in the output.

Providing a function that takes an input file stream and an output file stream is a good idea.  And the test program shows how simple it becomes to make use of standard input and standard output for testing.

Comment: Apologize for the late reply, but thank you! This is working perfectly and this approach is amazing and way better than mine. Thanks again!